# match pattern and replace the match line with the next matching line in the same file

Tags: xml, awk, sed

I have an xml below

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <testsuites name ="first node"><!-- Firstnode testsuites -->
      <testsuite name ="first node"> <!-- firstnode testsuite -->
        <properties>
            <property name="assert-passed" value="1"/>
        </properties>
        <testcase  time="10">
        </testcase>
    <testsuite name ="second node" > <!-- secondnode testsuite -->
        <properties>
            <property name="assert-passed" value="1"/>
        </properties>
        <testcase  time="10">
        </testcase>
        <testcase   time="10">
        </testcase>
    <testsuite name ="third node"> <!-- thirdnode testsuite -->
        <properties>
            <property name="assert-passed" value="1"/>
        </properties>
        <testcase time="10">
            <failure  type="failure">
            unknown error</failure>
        </testcase>
        <testsuite name ="fourth node" > <!-- fourthnode testsuite -->
    </testsuite>
        <testsuites name ="second node" > <!-- secondnode testsuites -->
    </testsuites>
```

there are nodes

> testsuites

and

> testsuite

what i want to do is

1. remove the first matching node of **testsuites** and replace with the
   next matching node of **testsuites**
2. remove the first matching node of  and replace with the
   second matching node of **testsuites** , second matched with third etc

basically want to replace the node with the following node.the expected outcome is to be

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <testsuites name ="second node" > <!--secondnode testsuites -->
      <testsuite name ="second node" > <!-- secondnode testsuite -->
        <properties>
            <property name="assert-passed" value="1"/>
        </properties>
        <testcase  time="10">
        </testcase>
    <testsuite name = "third node"> <!-- thirdnode testsuite -->
        <properties>
            <property name="assert-passed" value="1"/>
        </properties>
        <testcase  time="10">
        </testcase>
        <testcase   time="10">
        </testcase>
    <testsuite name = "fourth node" > <!-- fourthnode testsuite -->
        <properties>
            <property name="assert-passed" value="1"/>
        </properties>
        <testcase time="10">
            <failure  type="failure">
            unknown error</failure>
        </testcase>
        </testsuite>

            </testsuites>
```

I am using the below awk command

```
awk '{
    if($0~/<testsuite errors/)
    {
        a=$0;
        print $0;
        print "firstmatch";
            getline;
            b=$0;
            if(b~/<testsuite errors/)
            {
            print "iamher";
            print b;
            a==b;
            print a;
            }
        #print a;
    }
    else
    {
    #print $0
    }
}'
```

this one output but not going into the inside if where i swap the lines.
what is i am mising

Comment: I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: your input xml is invalid. Post a valid testable xlml structure

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest edited the xml pls have a look

Comment: the xml is not valid , so if i make the changes it will become valid that's what i am looking for help. move nodes and remove unwanted so the xml becomes valid one